# Queueing system with priority or client pull?

Tags: activemq-classic, priority-queue, polling, stomp

I'm working on a project in which multiple workers receive STOMP messages from a queue of jobs for processing, and we'd like to have priorities supported.  Currently, we're using ActiveMQ, but we haven't been able to get the built-in priority support to work properly, and have had to resort to using multiple queues, one per priority.  This works, but for the fact that there is always at least one unacknowledged message client-side in each queue's buffer, waiting to be ACKed.  If several thousand messages come in one one priority, any of the messages in the buffers for lower priorities could conceivably sit there for hours or even days at a time.

It would be nice if we could poll the server for a message instead of passively waiting, but this doesn't seem supported unless we use OpenWire, which seems like overkill.  Any suggestions on solutions we might use?

Edit: it occurred to me to mention what I meant when I said we couldn't get the priorities to work.  When we tested ActiveMQ's priorities, it seemed to stop respecting them once a large enough backlog occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case sounds like an ideal time to start using an openwire client as that supports both message pull and also client side priority ordering for cases where the broker isn't able to honor the priority.  I'm not really sure why you think that it's overkill but it seems like overkill might be just what you need.

Comment: Overkill in that it would require a complete rewrite and even a switch in language.  Currently, the work is done in Perl, and OpenWire support seems almost completely lacking; thus, we'd have to write our own library.  Cursory searching seems to indicate that Ruby and Python might have better support.

Comment: If that's the way I have to go, so be it, but I thought I'd pick the brains of experts first.